# Can't find python package "jsonpath"

Tags: python-2.7, pip, jsonpath

When using pip, I cannot seem to find the proper way to install the module "jsonpath".

```
      pip install jsonpath
```

Give me the age-old return of:

```
      Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Jsonpath (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Jsonpath
```

Anyone who has installed this package before have the proper 
command? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Use `pip install jsonpath-rw` insted

> > Windows PowerShell
> >     Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
> >     PS C:\Users\****> pip install jsonpath
> >     Collecting jsonpath
> >       Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jsonpath (from versions: )
> >     No matching distribution found for jsonpath
> >
> > PS C:\Users\****> pip install jsonpath-rw
> >     Collecting jsonpath-rw
> >       Downloading jsonpath-rw-1.4.0.tar.gz
> >     Collecting ply (from jsonpath-rw)
> >       Downloading ply-3.8.tar.gz (157kB)
> >         100% |################################| 163kB 1.2MB/s
> >     Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): decorator in   c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from jsonpath-rw)
> >     Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in c:\python27 \lib\site-packages (from jsonpath-rw)
> >     Building wheels for collected packages: jsonpath-rw, ply
> >       Running setup.py bdist_wheel for jsonpath-rw ... done
> >       Stored in directory: C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\5a\b2\15\41b01c9fcbfe11c8390cd3e1bb9c02d12d22ec15e34698adcb
> >       Running setup.py bdist_wheel for ply ... done
> >       Stored in directory: C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\d9\34\fe\b9f5d00d8690911944b0c24811ed7f5fb2c5d89f9c4d6053c7
> >     Successfully built jsonpath-rw ply
> >     Installing collected packages: ply, jsonpath-rw
> >     Successfully installed jsonpath-rw-1.4.0 ply-3.8
> >     PS C:\Users\****>

Comment: I have tried that, but the import will not be the same. It won't work for something like this either: http://mikelev.in/2012/08/implementing-jsonpath-in-python-with-examples/

Comment: Have you tried xjpath? it is listed as alternative to jsonpath. Also try giving `pip search jsonpath` that will list available packages that you can research and choose to install

Answer (score 0):

Have encountered the same problem.

You can not install jsonpath by `pip install jsonpath`, you can download the source code [here](http://www.ultimate.com/phil/python/download/jsonpath-0.54.tar.gz) and install it manually.

It seems that the author has removed all packages from pypi.python.org, that's why we cannot install jsonpath by pip, you can see  [the links for jsonpath](https://pypi.python.org/simple/jsonpath/) is empty.

The author [has declared](http://www.ultimate.com/phil/python/#jsonpath):

> I regard this as a toy

So, I am using [jsonpath-rw](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonpath-rw) instead now.